# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when connecting to gmail pop3 server

Tags: java, gmail, ssl-certificate, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have some trouble when I try to connect to gmail POP3 server with javamail.

My error is:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

It's blocking at the store.connect line.

Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_66\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        prop.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        prop.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
        prop.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        prop.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.pop3.user", username);
        prop.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
        sess = Session.getInstance(prop,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, pwd);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Obtention d'un objet store");
        st = sess.getStore("pop3");
        st.connect(host, username, pwd); //Blocking HERE
```

I checked my path and it's ok so I don't understand what is the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: I use java 1.8.0